# Apex code to access external files datasource e.g. sharepointonline

Tags: file-storage

I've got files connect set up to access sharepoint.  I'm however also interested in using Apex code to browse this external data source like.  Is this possible?  if so can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access via apex SOQL.

If you go to your schema builder or workbench you will find an external object created with __x .You can run SOQL on these and show on Visualforce Page .

Please also note some of the considerations

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=platform_connect_considerations_soql.htm&language=en_US